# Google functions firestore snapshot return after empty

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using triggers for firestore on "Products" collection.
The trigger calls the "products" function. However, change.before.data() returns data before the update.
But the "change.after.data() is returned empty

Code:

```
// that's how it works:
export const produtosWrite = functions.firestore.document('estabelecimentos/{idLoja}/privado/estoque/produtos/{idProduto}')
        .onWrite((change, context)=> {
            functions.logger.debug("after:", change.after.data(), change.after.exists);
            return true;
        })

//that doesn't work:
export const produtosWrite = functions.firestore.document('estabelecimentos/{idLoja}/privado/estoque/produtos/{idProduto}')
    .onWrite((change, context)=> {
        if(change.after.exists) {
            functions.logger.debug("after2:", change.after.data());
        }
        return true;
    })
```

Comment: Do you delete the doc? Can you check if `change.after.exists` returns `true`?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, return true.

Answer (score 1):

use an if statement that checks and returns data or not.

here's the code:-

```
export const produtosWrite = functions.firestore.document('/estabelecimentos/{idLoja}/privado/estoque/produtos/{idProduto}')
.onWrite((change, context)=> {
        if (change.before.exists) {
            functions.logger.debug("before:", change.before.data());
        }
        else (change.after.exists) {
            functions.logger.debug("before (deleted):", change.before.data());

        }
})
```

Comment: it returns true. But even so after returns empty

Comment: not working. After empty return.